# TimePickerDialog Exception

Tags: android, timepickerdialog

description:

I use TimePickerDialog , when I click my Button , an exception occurred.

Here is my Source Code:

```
private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute, int second) {
        String theTime = null;
        String thetimeStr = ((hourOfDay != 0) ? "%1$s" + " " + getString(R.string.hour_lowercase) + " " : "")
                + ((minute != 0) ? "%2$s" + " " + getString(R.string.minute_lowercase) + " " : "")
                + ((second != 0) ? "%3$s" + " " + getString(R.string.second_lowercase) : "");
        theTime = String.format(thetimeStr, hourOfDay, minute, second);
        String intervalInfo = mUploadIntervalTextView.getText() + theTime;
        mUploadIntervalTextView.setText(String.valueOf(intervalInfo));
        if ((hourOfDay * 3600 + minute * 60 + second) != 0) {
            mSharedPreference.edit().putInt(ServerMonitorPlus.UPLOAD_ERROR_DATA_INTERVAL,
                    (hourOfDay * 3600 + minute * 60 + second)).apply();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(ReportServerConfigurationActivity.this,
                    getResources().getString(R.string.interval_error),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
};

mPickTimeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int interval = mSharedPreference.getInt(ServerMonitorPlus.UPLOAD_ERROR_DATA_INTERVAL,300);
            int hour = interval / 3600;
            int minute = interval % 3600 / 60;
            int second = interval % 3600 % 60;
            TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(ReportServerConfigurationActivity.this,
                    mTimeSetListener, hour, minute,second, true);
            timePickerDialog.show();
        }
    });
```

Here is my xml layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/last_upload_textView"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:hint="@string/ip_address"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/upload_error_info_interval"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:text="@string/upload_interval_seconds"
    />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/pick_time_btn"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/ip_address_editText"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/domain_name_edit" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/is_start_upload_error_checkBox"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/enable_upload_error_info"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/test_btn"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/test"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

When I click my button , I got following problem

Here is the error details:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class com.luckyxmobile.servermonitorplus.timepicker.TimePicker
                                                                              Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class com.luckyxmobile.servermonitorplus.timepicker.TimePicker
                                                                              Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
                                                                                  at com.luckyxmobile.servermonitorplus.timepicker.TimePickerDialog.<init>(TimePickerDialog.java:109)
                                                                                  at com.luckyxmobile.servermonitorplus.timepicker.TimePickerDialog.<init>(TimePickerDialog.java:79)
                                                                                  at com.luckyxmobile.servermonitorplus.activity.ReportServerConfigurationActivity$3.onClick(ReportServerConfigurationActivity.java:134)
                                                                                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5609)
                                                                                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22262)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
                                                                               Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #34: Binary XML file line #34: Error inflating class com.luckyxmobile.servermonitorplus.numberpicker.NumberPicker
                                                                               Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #34: Error inflating class com.luckyxmobile.servermonitorplus.numberpicker.NumberPicker
                                                                               Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
                                                                                  at com.luckyxmobile.servermonitorplus.timepicker.TimePicker.<init>(TimePicker.java:159)
                                                                                  at com.luckyxmobile.servermonitorplus.timepicker.TimePicker.<init>(TimePicker.java:140)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
                                                                                  at com.luckyxmobile.servermonitorplus.timepicker.TimePickerDialog.<init>(TimePickerDialog.java:109)
                                                                                  at com.luckyxmobile.servermonitorplus.timepicker.TimePickerDialog.<init>(TimePickerDialog.java:79)

 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5609)
                                                                                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22262)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
                                                                               Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
                                                                                  at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue(ResourcesImpl.java:190)
                                                                                  at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2094)
                                                                                  at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1111)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:424)
                                                                                  at com.luckyxmobile.servermonitorplus.numberpicker.NumberPicker.<init>(NumberPicker.java:637)
                                                                                  at com.luckyxmobile.servermonitorplus.numberpicker.NumberPicker.<init>(NumberPicker.java:562)
```

There is my Activity Source Code:

```
public class ReportServerConfigurationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ServerMonitorPlus mServerMonitor;
private EditText mIpAddressEditText;
private Button mTestBtn,mPickTimeBtn;
private CheckBox mIsUploadErrorCheckBox;
private TextView mReportTimeTextView,mUploadIntervalTextView;
private SharedPreferences mSharedPreference;
private Retrofit mRetrofit;
private UpLoadErrorInfoService upLoadErrorInfoService;
private MenuItem miActionProgressItem;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.report_server_activity);
    findViews();
    initValues();
    setListeners();
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.progress_action, menu);
    // Store instance of the menu item containing progress
    miActionProgressItem = menu.findItem(R.id.miActionProgress);
    // Extract the action-view from the menu item
    // Return to finish
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

private void initValues() {
    mSharedPreference = getSharedPreferences(ServerMonitorPlus.SEND_ERROR_PREF, 0);
}

private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute, int second) {
        String theTime = null;
        String theTimeStr = ((hourOfDay != 0) ? "%1$s" + " " + getString(R.string.hour_lowercase) + " " : "")
                + ((minute != 0) ? "%2$s" + " " + getString(R.string.minute_lowercase) + " " : "")
                + ((second != 0) ? "%3$s" + " " + getString(R.string.second_lowercase) : "");
        theTime = String.format(theTimeStr, hourOfDay, minute, second);
        String intervalInfo = mUploadIntervalTextView.getText() + theTime;
        mUploadIntervalTextView.setText(String.valueOf(intervalInfo));
        if ((hourOfDay * 3600 + minute * 60 + second) != 0) {
            mSharedPreference.edit().putInt(ServerMonitorPlus.UPLOAD_ERROR_DATA_INTERVAL,
                    (hourOfDay * 3600 + minute * 60 + second)).apply();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(ReportServerConfigurationActivity.this,
                    getResources().getString(R.string.interval_error),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
};

private void setListeners() {
    mIpAddressEditText.addTextChangedListener(new IpWatcher());

    mTestBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            testServer(true);

        }
    });


    mPickTimeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int interval = mSharedPreference.getInt(ServerMonitorPlus.UPLOAD_ERROR_DATA_INTERVAL,300);
            int hour = interval / 3600;
            int minute = interval % 3600 / 60;
            int second = interval % 3600 % 60;
            TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(ReportServerConfigurationActivity.this,
                    mTimeSetListener, hour, minute,second, true);
            timePickerDialog.show();
        }
    });

    mIsUploadErrorCheckBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            boolean isChecked = mIsUploadErrorCheckBox.isChecked();
            Log.d("DEBUG","isChecked"+isChecked);
            if (isChecked) {
                testServer(false); 
                boolean ipOK = mSharedPreference.getBoolean(ServerMonitorPlus.IS_TEST_IP_OK, false);
                if (ipOK) { 
                    long currentMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    int interval = mSharedPreference.getInt(ServerMonitorPlus.UPLOAD_ERROR_DATA_INTERVAL, 300);
                    Log.d("DEBUG","is-permitted-to-upload"+mSharedPreference.getBoolean(ServerMonitorPlus.IS_PERMITTED_TO_UPLOAD,false));
                    mSharedPreference.edit().putLong(TIME_OF_START_UPLOAD_ERROR, currentMillis - interval * 1000).apply();
                    mSharedPreference.edit().putLong(TIME_OF_END_UPLOAD_ERROR, currentMillis).apply();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(ReportServerConfigurationActivity.this, SendErrorService.class);
                    startService(intent);
                }else {

                }
            } else {
                // 取消上传
                Log.i("调试", "onClick-no checked");
                mSharedPreference.edit().putBoolean(ServerMonitorPlus.IS_PERMITTED_TO_UPLOAD, false).apply();
            }
        }
    });

}

private void testServer(final boolean isTestOnly) {
    hideKeyboard();
    final String url = mIpAddressEditText.getText().toString();
    mRetrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(urlHeader + url + testUrlTail)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
            .build();
    upLoadErrorInfoService = mRetrofit.create(UpLoadErrorInfoService.class);
    if (IsInternet.checkNetwork(ReportServerConfigurationActivity.this)) {
        upLoadErrorInfoService.loadRepo()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Subscriber<TestIpInfo>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onStart() {
                        super.onStart();
                        miActionProgressItem.setVisible(true);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {
                        miActionProgressItem.setVisible(false);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        miActionProgressItem.setVisible(false);
                        DialogAdapter adapter = new DialogAdapter(ReportServerConfigurationActivity.this);
                        adapter.createDialog(getString(R.string.server_configuration_is_unavailable));
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(TestIpInfo testIpInfo) {
                        if (testIpInfo != null ) {
                            if(isTestOnly){ //如果仅仅是测试的话就弹出对话框提示测试成功
                                DialogAdapter adapter = new DialogAdapter(ReportServerConfigurationActivity.this);
                                adapter.createDialog(getString(R.string.server_configuration_is_ok));
                            }else { //如果是上传的话再保存
                                mSharedPreference.edit().putBoolean(ServerMonitorPlus.IS_PERMITTED_TO_UPLOAD,true).apply();
                            }
                            mSharedPreference.edit().putBoolean(ServerMonitorPlus.IS_TEST_IP_OK,true).apply();
                            mSharedPreference.edit().putString(ServerMonitorPlus.IP_ADDRESS,url).apply();
                        }

                    }

                });
    }

}


private void findViews() {
    mIpAddressEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ip_address_editText);
    mTestBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.test_btn);
    mIsUploadErrorCheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.is_start_upload_error_checkBox);
    mServerMonitor = (ServerMonitorPlus) getApplicationContext();
    mReportTimeTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.last_upload_textView);
    mUploadIntervalTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.upload_error_info_interval);
    mPickTimeBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pick_time_btn);
}

private class IpWatcher implements TextWatcher {

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    }
}

public void hideKeyboard() {
    View view = getCurrentFocus();
    if (view != null) {
        ((InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).
                hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
    }
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    MobclickAgent.onPageEnd("ReportServerConfigurationActivity");
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    MobclickAgent.onPageStart("ReportServerConfigurationActivity");
    long lastUploadTime = mSharedPreference.getLong(TIME_OF_END_UPLOAD_ERROR, -1);
    String currentTime;
    if(lastUploadTime == -1){
        currentTime = TimeFormatter.getLocalTime(System.currentTimeMillis(), this, "yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm");
    }else {
        currentTime = TimeFormatter.getLocalTime(lastUploadTime, this, "yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm");
    }
    mReportTimeTextView.setText(getString(R.string.last_report_time) + " " + currentTime);
    Log.d("DEBUG","currentTime"+currentTime);
    boolean isUploadPermitted = mSharedPreference.getBoolean(ServerMonitorPlus.IS_PERMITTED_TO_UPLOAD, false);
    Log.d("DEBUG","isUploadPermitted"+isUploadPermitted);
    if (isUploadPermitted) {
        mIsUploadErrorCheckBox.setChecked(true);
    } else {
        mIsUploadErrorCheckBox.setChecked(false);
    }
    String ipAddress = mSharedPreference.getString(ServerMonitorPlus.IP_ADDRESS, "");
    Log.d("DEBUG","ipAddress"+ipAddress);
    mIpAddressEditText.setText(ipAddress);
}}
```

Here is My TimePickerDialog

```
public class TimePickerDialog extends AlertDialog
    implements OnClickListener, OnTimeChangedListener {

public interface OnTimeSetListener {


    void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute,int second);
}

private static final String HOUR = "hour";
private static final String MINUTE = "minute";
private static final String SECOND = "second";
private static final String IS_24_HOUR = "is24hour";

private final TimePicker mTimePicker;
private final OnTimeSetListener mCallback;

int mInitialHourOfDay;
int mInitialMinute;
int mInitialSecond;
boolean mIs24HourView;

/**
 * @param context Parent.
 * @param callBack How parent is notified.
 * @param hourOfDay The initial hour.
 * @param minute The initial minute.
 * @param is24HourView Whether this is a 24 hour view, or AM/PM.
 */
public TimePickerDialog(Context context,
        OnTimeSetListener callBack,
        int hourOfDay, int minute, int second, boolean is24HourView) {
    this(context, Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB ? R.style.Theme_Dialog_Alert : 0, callBack, hourOfDay, minute, second, is24HourView);
}

/**
 * @param context Parent.
 * @param theme the theme to apply to this dialog
 * @param callBack How parent is notified.
 * @param hourOfDay The initial hour.
 * @param minute The initial minute.
 * @param is24HourView Whether this is a 24 hour view, or AM/PM.
 */
public TimePickerDialog(Context context,
        int theme,
        OnTimeSetListener callBack,
        int hourOfDay, int minute, int second, boolean is24HourView) {
    super(context, theme);
    mCallback = callBack;
    mInitialHourOfDay = hourOfDay;
    mInitialMinute = minute;
    mInitialSecond = second;
    mIs24HourView = is24HourView;

    setIcon(0);
    setTitle(R.string.time_picker_dialog_title);

    Context themeContext = getContext();
    setButton(BUTTON_POSITIVE, themeContext.getText(R.string.date_time_done), this);

    LayoutInflater inflater =
            (LayoutInflater) themeContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.time_picker_dialog, null);
    setView(view);
    mTimePicker = (TimePicker) view.findViewById(R.id.timePicker);

    // initialize state
    mTimePicker.setIs24HourView(mIs24HourView);
    mTimePicker.setCurrentHour(mInitialHourOfDay);
    mTimePicker.setCurrentMinute(mInitialMinute);
    mTimePicker.setCurrentSecond(mInitialSecond);
    mTimePicker.setOnTimeChangedListener(this);
}

public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    tryNotifyTimeSet();
}

public void updateTime(int hourOfDay, int minutOfHour, int secondofminute) {
    mTimePicker.setCurrentHour(hourOfDay);
    mTimePicker.setCurrentMinute(minutOfHour);
    mTimePicker.setCurrentSecond(secondofminute);
}

public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute, int second) {
    /* do nothing */
}

private void tryNotifyTimeSet() {
    if (mCallback != null) {
        mTimePicker.clearFocus();
        mCallback.onTimeSet(mTimePicker, mTimePicker.getCurrentHour(),
                mTimePicker.getCurrentMinute(),mTimePicker.getCurrentSecond());
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    tryNotifyTimeSet();
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
public Bundle onSaveInstanceState() {
    Bundle state = super.onSaveInstanceState();
    state.putInt(HOUR, mTimePicker.getCurrentHour());
    state.putInt(MINUTE, mTimePicker.getCurrentMinute());
    state.putInt(SECOND,mTimePicker.getCurrentSecond());
    state.putBoolean(IS_24_HOUR, mTimePicker.is24HourView());
    return state;
}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    int hour = savedInstanceState.getInt(HOUR);
    int minute = savedInstanceState.getInt(MINUTE);
    int second = savedInstanceState.getInt(SECOND);
    mTimePicker.setIs24HourView(savedInstanceState.getBoolean(IS_24_HOUR));
    mTimePicker.setCurrentHour(hour);
    mTimePicker.setCurrentMinute(minute);
    mTimePicker.setCurrentSecond(second);
}}
```

Comment: Try posting your whole java class code. It's tough to tell the order of things the way you've posted it. Also, could you post your TimePickerDialog code?

Comment: @idratherbeintheair  I have pasted my code.

Comment: Where's your NumberPicker class?

Comment: @idratherbeintheair Does it need NumberPick? I just use TimePickDialog

Comment: I think your error is originally from a NumberPicker exception.